# Your username and password don't match

Tags: google-account

I've tried to log in to my Google Account on my phone and tablet, I've tried on a friends HTC and mine are Samsung. On all the devices, I get "Your username and password don't match" and instructions to reset the password. I have tried countless times, reset the password about 5 times and double checked, even quadruple checked. Tried copying and pasting the password, etc. I have tried logging in on the browsewr, it works fine. I have tried enabling access for less secure apps/devices, still nothing. 2 factor wasn't on, I tried turning it on twice, still nothing. Restarting the phone, checking the date, etc. I have tried signing in with a different Google account on the phone and it works like a charm but mine doesn't. I have been searching for hours, checked numerous Stack Overflow posts, Android Forums, etc. There (should) only be 1 Google Account (well, there isn't any in the settings right now). I **think** this was working before I factory reset it, but not sure.

TL;DR: Correct password, enabled & disabled less secure apps, tried turning off 2 factor, other account works, tried on other devices. Still nothing.

WTL;DR Not working, tried everything.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your Google account settings from a browser and setup an App Password for the device.  I chose the option "Other..." from the app drop down list so that I could easily identify the device should I decide to revoke it later.

The sign-in problem was due to the Two-Step verification process I had previously setup on my account.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so. I have a Samsung Galaxy S first generation. I've been trying to look for an answer but haven't found one. However, after trying different things out myself, I finally got it to work.

This is what I did:
After factory resetting your phone, skip the "add google account" and instead go through the next step and "add an email account" using the same google account details.

After you have successfully added the email account, you can now open the Market or Play Store where it will tell you to add a Google Account. Now you should be able to add the same Google Account without the "Sorry username and password does not match" problem.

Good Luck.

Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

After a factory reset I had similar problem. The following is how I solved this problem:

I went to [Google Accounts](https://accounts.google.com/), then I signed in with the account I wanted to use with the device.

Inside the signing in to Google subsection, I disabled 2 step verification. Then, in the connected apps and sites subsection, I turned on the option to allow less secure apps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It worked when I changed this settings: "Allowing less secure apps to access your account"  https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en